# Minimize floating windows in NetBeans 7.2

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.2

I recently upgraded to NetBeans 7.2 and am facing a substantial usability issue with floating windows. In 7.1 each floating window was minimize-able, which I used quite regularly. By all appearances the minimize button is completely gone. The button is missing and when I right click on the title bar, the close button is available but the minimize is disabled (greyed out).

I'm running windows 7 x64.

I also encountered the issue in the RC but figured that it would be resolve in the final version. I've googled around and not been able to find anyone with the same issue so I'm hoping that it is just me.

I checked out the settings under Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Windows and none of them seem to make any difference.

How can I get the minimize floating windows functionality back?

Comment: Submitted bug report here: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=216484

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a bug on the windows version, because I'm using the mac one and the minimize buttons are in place.

I'd go back to the previous version until they solve the bug.

In fact, at least in mac, you can have both versions installed, so you could open 7.2 from time to time and check for any updates that solved the problem.

I've found some additional info here:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=216019

Maybe you could try to do as they tell:

> No minimize button means those windows are docked into editor docking spot. Use
>   menu Window - Reset Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it made no difference.

Comment: "No minimize button means those windows are docked into editor docking spot. Use menu Window - Reset Windows." helped me to make windows floating.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to minimize windows in netbeans on win 7x64

And sorry I wanted to add this as a comment, but apparently I couldn't